# Coordinates in Rectangle Java class

Tags: java

This is my code please help!
Cannot convert my int to a boolean haha
I'm sure there are many problems with this code as well.
If anyone can explain that would be awesome!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab2
   {
      public static void main(String[] args)
         { 
            int width = -10 <= 10;
            int height = -5 <= 5;
            double choice1;
            double choice2;
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter X and Y coordinates.");
            choice1 = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
            choice2 = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(1);
            if (choice1 == width || choice2 == height)
            System.out.println("Coordinates are out of the rectangle.");
            else System.out.println("Coordinates are in the rectangle.");

         }
    }
```

Comment: Whats the issue? What is the input you are providing and output you are getting?

Comment: `int width = -10 <= 10;` doesn't make sense - what is it you're hoping to achieve?

Comment: My assignment is "Write a program that prompts the user to enter a point (x, y) and checks whether the point is within the rectangle centered at (0, 0) with width 10 and height 5"

Comment: I'm making this a comment, not an answer, because I'm not sure either, but I think that statement is an attempt to define a range of allowable coordinates. If that is the case, OP needs to explicitly state upper and lower limits, and individually check against those.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code. Firstly the way you are reading those `doubles` – look at the documentation for `charAt()`. `Double.parseDouble` is what you want.

Then there is your definition of `width` and `height` – Java will not magically do what you want, those variables need to be assigned numbers, not ranges of numbers.

Lastly, there is the check for whether the point is inside the rectangle – you may want to draw this on paper to get a clear idea of what is going on.

Here is the code with fixes for these issues:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
         int width = 10;
         int height = 5;
         double x = 0, y = 0;
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter X coordinate:");
         try {
             x = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());
             System.out.println("Enter Y coordinate:");
             y = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());
         } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
             System.out.println("You didn't enter a number. Exiting.");
             return;
         }
         if (x < -width/2 || x > width/2 || y < -height/2 || y > height/2)
             System.out.println("Coordinates are out of the rectangle.");
         else
             System.out.println("Coordinates are in the rectangle.");
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

As requested, entering both coordinates on the same line:

```
System.out.println("Enter coordinates separated by a comma:");
String[] input = keyboard.nextLine().split(",");
if(input.length != 2) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input. Exiting.");
    return;
}
try {
    x = Double.parseDouble(input[0]);
    System.out.println("Enter Y coordinate:");
    y = Double.parseDouble(input[1]);
}
```

Comment: hmmm, thanks for the information! The assignment says to have the user enter two coordinates at once so how would one go about doing that?